# What is the lower bound for highly composite numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

if $x=d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, what is the tightest lower-bound for $n$ only given $x$?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will start off with the simplest type, $$ d(n) \leq \sqrt{3 n} $$ and $$ d(n) \leq 48 \left(\frac{n}{2520}\right)^{1/3} $$ and
$$ d(n) \leq 576 \left(\frac{n}{21621600}\right)^{1/4}. $$
The first one has equality only  at $n = 12,$   second only at $n =2520,$ third only at $n= 21621600.$   Instead of continuing with fractional powers $1/k$ the better results switch to logarithms. Reference is a 1988 paper by J. L. Nicolas in a book called Ramanujan Revisited.

With equality at $n = 6983776800 = 2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$ Full details of the proof appear in J.-L. Nicolas et G. Robin. *Majorations explicites pour le nombre de diviseurs de n*, Canad. Math. Bull., 26, 1983, 485--492. The next two appear in the dissertation of Robin, are repeated in the 1988 Nicolas survey article indicated.

With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}.   $$ Compare this one with Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, attributed to Wigert (1907),
$$ \limsup \frac{\log d(n)  \log \log n}{\log n} = \log 2.  $$

With equality at a number $n$ near $3.309 \cdot 10^{135},$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\log \log n} + \frac{4.762350121177...}{\left(\log \log n \right)^2} \right)}   $$

Just to fill in one blank, the special integers $n$ here are "superior highly composite numbers" using Ramanujan's original recipe for prime factorization, which I like to write, with  $ \delta > 0,$ as
$$ N_\delta = \prod_p \; p^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{p^\delta - 1} \right\rfloor  } $$
The first (largest) $\delta$ that assigns an exponent $k$ to a prime $p$ is 
$$ \delta = \frac{\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)}{\log p}.  $$
See [Is there a formula that can predict the primes in the sequence of ratios of consecutive superior highly composite numbers? : $2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7,...$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185493/is-there-a-formula-that-can-predict-the-primes-in-the-sequence-of-ratios-of-cons/185529#185529) for some detail, with computations.

So $$  N_{1/2} = 12, \;  N_{1/3} = 2520, \;  N_{1/4} = 21621600, $$
$$  N_{0.23} = 6983776800, \;  N_{0.155} \approx 6.929 \cdot 10^{40}, \;  N_{0.1218} \approx 3.309 \cdot 10^{135}.$$

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, let $x=d(n)$, then inverting the bounds given above,  $x^2/3 \leq n,   2520(x/48)^3 \leq n, 21621600(x/576)^4 \leq n$, and soon.  The more ambitious can try inverting the bound involving logarithms.  Gerhard "Leaves Something For Future Readers" Paseman, 2015.12.04

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to have an inequality $n \ge f(x)$. If the poser wants numerical results, here are two:

The least number having exactly x divisors is given by OEIS sequence http://www.oeis.org/A005179. It is a pretty wild function. The nice paper by Grost is recommended.

The least number having x (or more) divisors is given by the OEIS sequence http://www.oeis.org/A061799.