# On a claim of Ramanujan in his "Lost Notebook".

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

As I was flipping through the scanned version of Ramanujan's "[Lost Notebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_lost_notebook)" in our library, I came across a result which caught my attention. And as any excited teenager would do, I immediately photographed that page and put it up here.

[image]

The result in the photo is as follows.

> If $S(N)$ be the number of ways in which $N$ can be expressed as the sum of 2 squares, then the max. order of $S(N)$
>   $$= \sqrt{\text{max order of }\\ d(N^2 +aN+b)} \cdot e^{O(\log N)^{1/2 + \epsilon}}$$

Has anyone come across any such result before? Is this result true?

Comment: and $d$ is  ...

Comment: $d$ must be the number of divisors of a positive integer, $d(n) = \sigma_0(n).$ Reading from Hardy and Wright, fifth edition paperback, section 16.7. Then the "average order" of $d(n)$ is section 18.2, $r(n)$ defined 16.9, then average order and max order in section 18.7. Oh, H+W $r(n)$ is $S(N)$ above.  Estimates on $r(n)$ are called the Gauss Circle Problem, upper bounds on $d(n)$ are http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43103/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-highly-composite-numbers/43105#43105  


Answer (score 5):

From Hardy and Wright, fifth edition paperback, I am going to call your $S(N)$  their $r(n).$ Chapter 18 is called The Order of Magnitude of Arithmetical Functions. In section 18.1,  Theorem 317 
$$     \limsup \frac{d(n) \log \log n}{\log n} \; = \; \log 2$$
with the comment

> Thus the true `maximum order' of
>   $d(n)$ is about $$ 2^{\log n / \log
> > \log n}    $$

Then in section 18.7,

> There is also a theorem corresponding
>   to Theorem 317; the maximum order of
>   $r(n)$ is $$    2^{ \frac{\log n}{2
> > \log \log n}   }   $$

So, if one takes the square root of the first, the result is the second. It is a bit unclear what is meant by the numbers $a,b.$ Anyway, there has been considerable work on both items, as separate estimation problems, see
[What is the lower bound for highly composite numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43103/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-highly-composite-numbers/43105#43105)

and, for example,
[What is the status of the Gauss Circle Problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19079/what-is-the-status-of-the-gauss-circle-problem) 
where the interior of the circle is included.