# Is the ratio of two consecutive superior highly composite numbers a prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is stated in several places, as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number), or [oeis](https://oeis.org/A000705), or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuperiorHighlyCompositeNumber.html) that the ratio of two consecutive superior highly composite numbers is a prime, and all of them give as the only reference a paper by Ramanujan:

Ramanujan, S. "Highly Composite Numbers." Proc. London Math. Soc. 14, 347-407, 1915.

On the other hand, the analogous result for colosally abundant numbers is presented as a conjecture. In fact, Alaoglu and Erdős prove that this is true assuming that any $\alpha$ satisfying that $p^\alpha, q^\alpha$ are rational numbers for two prime numbers $p\neq q$ must be an integer. This is a consequence of the four exponentials conjecture.

However, when looking at the Ramanujan's proof, I cannot see any difference between both cases. Namely, Ramanujan says (page 392) that "it is easily seen" from (195) and (196). The first reference states that a superior highly composite number $N_x$ is a product of primorials $p_1\#\cdots p_k\#$, where $p_r$ is the greatest prime not exceeding $(1+1/r)^x$, where $x=1/\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is the epsilon appearing in the definition of superior highly composite number.

The second reference is an equivalent formulation, namely, that $N=e^{\vartheta(2)^x+\vartheta(3/2)^x+\cdots }$

It seems to me that the situation is exactly the analogous one to that considered by Alaoglu and Erdős: the change from a number $N_x$ to the next one happens when some $(1+1/r)^x$ takes a prime value, and if this happens for two different $r$ at the same $x$, i.e., if $(1+1/r)^x=p$, $(1+1/s)^x=q$, then $p^{1/x}, q^{1/x}$ are rational numbers, and this leads to a contradiction if we can conclude that $1/x$ is an integer.

So, my question is: is there really an argument proving that the ratio of two consecutive superior highly composite numbers is a prime not relying in the above-mentioned unproven conjecture?

Is seems that a negative answer is implicit in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185493/is-there-a-formula-that-can-predict-the-primes-in-the-sequence-of-ratios-of-cons), but it seems strange to me that the statement is still be presented everywhere as a proven fact.

Comment: So there is only a single paper that only contains a partial proof ("it is easily seen"). That sounds to me like something you might want to double check, maybe it is not that easy to see after all? :)

Comment: I guess that Ramanujan's "theorem" depends on the conjecture about powers of primes, exactly as Erdős' conjecture does, but, since it is stated as a theorem everywhere, I would like to know the opinion of an expert.